# how do you use meteorite with development releases of meteor?

Tags: meteor, meteorite

i'm using the latest shark release of meteor to gain access to the new Blaze UI system, but I can't use mrt with it. How can I do both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
mrt --release shark-1-29-2014-e
```

or

```
mrt update --release shark-1-29-2014-e
```

These may work for newer projects, but it is also possible to use the `--branch` flag, like so:

```
mrt create app_name --branch shark
```

Comment: it says 'Can't specify a release when running Meteor from a checkout.' ...is there a way to use meteorite without it running meteor from a checkout??

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure how to use meteorite with a checkout. If you just use it regularly you can specify the release fine. You won't get the absolute newest version of the `shark` branch, but it's not exactly stable no matter what.

Comment: how do i use it "regularly"?

Comment: `sudo npm install -g meteorite` - `mrt create foo` - `cd foo` - `mrt --release shark-1-29-2014-e`

Comment: im pretty sure that's how i originally installed meteorite. i think they were referring to meteor itself. who knows, but i got it to work for a new project by simply doing 'mrt create app_name --branch shark'. im just going to move my code into there and not worry about converting an old app--all should get solid when the Meteor 1.0 launches.

Comment: Can you post your `smart.json` file?

Comment: I found out that these commands do not work for me therefore I opted for pinning the branch down on my smart.json. I add `"meteor": {"git": "https://github.com/meteor/meteor.git", "branch":"shark"},` just before `"packages" : {` and run with `mrt`